# is there any way to set new Android support AutoSize Textview in a style file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, autosize

I'm trying to use new [Android Support AutoSize](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) but all examples I've seen are adding it in the layout. 
However I have implemented most of the texts using styles so I'd like to add it there in order to reach easily all views. 
As I am using support I don't have **app:text...** in the style file as we usually have with **android:test...**

Is there any way to add it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you should use these attributes without `android:` prefix

Like below

```
<style name="Text">
        <item name="autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
        <item name="autoSizeMaxTextSize">100sp</item>
        <item name="autoSizeMinTextSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```